# How to install a predefined package(class) in google colab(python,Jupyter notebook)?

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-notebook, package, google-colaboratory

I have already defined a class which I want to use in my code.
 in order to import it I know I have to install it first.(I am using google's colab)

to install first I uploaded the .py file into my drive which is mounted and no problem with that.

but still there is problem with installing the package.

how can I use this predefined class correctly in my code?

```
    !pip install robotdef.py
```

```
Collecting robotdef.py
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement robotdef.py (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for robotdef.py
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I overlooked one thing.

If "I uploaded the .py file into my drive which is mounted and no problem with that." is the situation, you don't have to run `pip`, but you'll need to expand the Python path to the directory where your package(class) is installed.

I hope this may help.

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/foo/bar/your-modules-path')
```

---

`pip` fetches a package from the Python Package Index (PyPI) repository. This means that the package must be registered on the repository first.

I tried to find 'robotdef.py' or 'robotdef' using a search form on [the PyPI website](https://pypi.org), but it seems that 'robotdef.py' hasn't been registered yet...

If it's on the repository, `!pip install <package name>` will work fine on the Colab.

***Supplement***

Sorry, my answer was incomplete.

It's not necessary a package to be registered on the PyPI repository, but you can [install a package from local archives](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-from-local-archives), etc.